# Is it possible serve django as a CGI on Apache

Tags: django, apache, cgi

I have a 'control panel' webserver account and I want to build a django powered site.

Mod_wsgi is not enabled/present, leaving CGI as my only option.

Mod_rewrite is available and I have been experimenting/hacking with these solutions, https://gist.github.com/philchristensen/5845530, [Django via CGI on shared hosting](http://joemaller.com/1467/django-via-cgi-on-shared-hosting/). Both of these are a number of years old and may no longer be relevant, plus I have had no luck with so far.

Does any know if what I am trying to do is even possible and, if so, how it may be dine

Comment: Why not change to a proper hosting company?

Comment: ....mmm. Budget says "No."